# How to Populate and Aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

i want to aggregate the ratings so i could get the total of feedbacks. But the thing is, it's referenced. Here's my schema

User

```
    username: String,
    fullname: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true
    },
  address: String,
  password: String,
  feedback: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Feedback'    
  }]
```

Feedback

```
var FeedbackSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    postname: String,
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    message: String,
    feedbacktype: String,
    thumbsup: Boolean,
    rating: {
        communication: Number,
        timeliness: Number,
        delivery: Number
    }
});
```

So what i want to achieve is, i will find the User by id then populate the feedbacks field, then i will aggregate the ratings on the feedback field so i would get a total of number of ratings for communication, for delivery and for timeliness. (The ratings are 1-5 stars)

Do you know how to aggregate and populate? thank you

**update

So i've run the aggregation to the user schema, now im getting 0 results from all ratings

```
User.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": ObjectId('593150f6ac4d9b0410d2aac0') } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "feedbacks",
    "localField": "feedback",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "feedback"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "username": 1,
    "fullname": 1,
    "email": 1,
    "password": 1,
    "rating": {
      "communication": { "$sum": "$feedback.rating.communication" },
      "timeliness": { "$sum": "$feedback.rating.timeliness" },
      "delivery": { "$sum": "$feedback.rating.delivery" }
    }
  }}
]).exec(function(err, a){
    console.log(a)
})
```

result `rating: { communication: 0, timeliness: 0, delivery: 0 } } ]`

also tried it with other users, all of them 0 result rating

Comment: Aggregate by what? The User? Some property on the user? If neither and it's just total ratings then you can just use the ratings collection. If you only really want this "per user", it's probably the least painful to just add up the fields from the results after populate. So per user I really only think this should matter if you want to do something like "sort" and "limit" based on the totals produced. What is your actual case??

Comment: sorry i don't know if aggregate is the right thing to do. So here's what i want to achieve, Users have lots of feedbacks, on the user schema the feedback is referenced, so i need to populate the feedback on user schema, then i will get the feedback data, now this feedback contains some information and i need to sum up the total of each rating under feedback. i need to total the communication rating, timeliness rating and delivery rating then send the data back to the front-end

Comment: For one user? For many? What is the use case?

Comment: Just for one user only. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple Listing to Follow

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/rating');

var userSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  feedback: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Feedback' }]
});

var feedbackSchema = new Schema({
  rating: {
    communication: Number,
    timeliness: Number,
    delivery: Number
  }
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
var Feedback = mongoose.model('Feedback', feedbackSchema);
async.series(
  [
    (callback) => {
      async.each([User,Feedback],(model,callback) => {
        model.remove({},callback);
      },callback);
    },

    (callback) => {
      async.waterfall(
        [
          (callback) => {
            async.map(
              [
                { "rating": {
                  "communication": 1, "timeliness": 2, "delivery": 3
                }},
                { "rating": {
                  "communication": 2, "timeliness": 3, "delivery": 4
                }}
              ],
              (item,callback) => {
                Feedback.create(item,callback)
              },
              callback
            );
          },
          (feedback, callback) => {
            User.create({ "username": "Bill", "feedback": feedback },callback);
          },
          (user, callback) => {
            User.aggregate([
              { "$match": { "_id": user._id } },
              { "$lookup": {
                "from": "feedbacks",
                "localField": "feedback",
                "foreignField": "_id",
                "as": "feedback"
              }},
              { "$project": {
                "username": 1,
                "rating": {
                  "communication": { "$sum": "$feedback.rating.communication" },
                  "timeliness": { "$sum": "$feedback.rating.timeliness" },
                  "delivery": { "$sum": "$feedback.rating.delivery" }
                }
              }}
            ],(err,results) => {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(results, undefined, 2));
              callback(err);
            });
          }
        ],
        callback
      )
    }
  ],
  (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

This will create two collections as User

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("593548455198ab3c09cf736b"),
        "username" : "Bill",
        "feedback" : [
                ObjectId("593548455198ab3c09cf7369"),
                ObjectId("593548455198ab3c09cf736a")
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
```

And feedbacks:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("593548455198ab3c09cf7369"),
        "rating" : {
                "communication" : 1,
                "timeliness" : 2,
                "delivery" : 3
        },
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("593548455198ab3c09cf736a"),
        "rating" : {
                "communication" : 2,
                "timeliness" : 3,
                "delivery" : 4
        },
        "__v" : 0
}
```

**Program Output** Shows the aggregation:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5935494a159c633c1b34807b",
    "username": "Bill",
    "rating": {
      "communication": 3,
      "timeliness": 5,
      "delivery": 7
    }
  }
]
```

Also `package.json` if the two dependencies are not clear enough:

```
{
  "name": "ratings",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.4.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.10.4"
  }
}
```

---

### Original Answer

Personally I would work this from the "Feedback" since you have the user already recorded there, and it is actually the way this scales better.

Instead of using population, we can instead use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) with a MongoDB server version of at least 3.2:

```
Feedback.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "user": userId } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$user",
    "communication": { "$sum": "$rating.communication" },
    "timeliness": { "$sum": "$rating.timeliness" },
    "delivery": { "$sum": "$rating.delivery" }
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "user"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$user" }
])
```

If you do not have a server version that supports `$lookup`then you can still "manually join" the User details with something like this:

```
Feedback.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "user": userId } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$user",
    "communication": { "$sum": "$rating.communication" },
    "timeliness": { "$sum": "$rating.timeliness" },
    "delivery": { "$sum": "$rating.delivery" }
  }}
],function(err, results) {
    result = results[0];
    User.findById(userId).lean().exec(function(err, user) {
      result.user = user;     // swap the _id for the Object

      // Then output result
    });
})
```

Which is basically what `.populate()` does, but we are doing it manually and efficiently for the result returned.

You can work the other way around from the `User` model, but it's likely more efficient to simply work this way around.

```
User.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": userid } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "feedbacks",
    "localField": "feedback",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "feedback"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "username": 1,
    "fullname": 1,
    "email": 1,
    "password": 1,
    "rating": {
      "communication": { "$sum": "$feedback.rating.communication" },
      "timeliness": { "$sum": "$feedback.rating.timeliness" },
      "delivery": { "$sum": "$feedback.rating.delivery" }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks! i'll try this one out and will give you a "Feedback"

Comment: just to clear things up. the "user" on "FeedbackSchema" is the user who gave feedback to other user. The thing i want is for the receiving user (which is the "UserSchema") populate the feedback schema that has ratings and user (which is the user who gave the feedback) sorry if its confusing

Comment: @John that would make big difference of course. Lucky I was just writing up the reverse process for the sake of it. Added the method from the `User` model perspective, which would appear to be the correct way around yes?

Comment: i tried it but sadly it didn't work. The feedback on userschema is an array of referenced objects.

Comment: @John I know that. That is what `$lookup` is for. The collection name must be different. Can you check your mongoose model and actual database. I thought the default mongoose "plural" would be "feedback", but it could possibly be "feedbacks"? Sounds wrong. But the point is since `$lookup` is a server operation, it needs the actual collection name.

Comment: @John Can you also look at your MongoDB server version. `$lookup` behaves differently with arrays in different versions, being in earlier versions we need to `$unwind` the array. So the things we need to know are the current server version, and the actual name of the collection for "Feedback" to go in the "from" argument.

Comment: on my user schema i defined it as "feedback". My Feedback schema is "Feedbacks". My mongo version is v3.4.4. Thank you!

Comment: i also tried the three different methods you posted but none works. i'll try it again wait

Comment: @John So you have a line like `mongoose.model("Feedback", feedBackSchema, "Feedbacks")`? That's the line I want to know or even if you can just check the database for the actual collection name? What is it? That is the name that needs to be supplied to `"from"` in the `$lookup` operation. So it doesn't work because you are not answering my question.

Comment: it's only this sir `module.exports = mongoose.model('Feedback', FeedbackSchema);`  on my database, it's pluralized

Comment: @John Okay when I do that with mongoose the collection name it gives me is actually "feedbacks", so that is what I have amended the bottom listing to do. What are you placing as the `userId` in the `$match` section? The intention is the `Objectid` from the `_id` field of the `User` we want. Check you have all the right details and run again.

Comment: i've placed a hardcoded id as userId `{ "$match": { "user": '593150f6ac4d9b0410d2aac0' } },` i've uploaded the code that i've implemented

Comment: @John You can't do that with the aggregation pipeline. You need to make it an `ObjectId` like this `{ "$match": { "user": ObjectId('593150f6ac4d9b0410d2aac0') } }`. Mongoose does not do autocasting in the aggregation pipeline.

Comment: @John `ObjectId = Mongoose.Types.ObjectId` will allow you to wrap the value.

Comment: thanks neil it works, but i encountered a problem. Please see the updated post. Thank you so much!

Comment: @John You are supposed to be using the aggregation on the `User` model. Also please do not post screenshots, but copy and paste the "text" instead. You are running the wrong aggregation.

Comment: sorry sir, so i aggregate on the user schema, but now i got 0 results on ratings. i updated my post

Comment: @John This is clearly a difficulty for you to understand. I'm writing a self contained listing to show results that you can hopefully follow. I'll comment when I have updated the post.

Comment: sorry sir. as of now im studying about this $lookup thing. anyway, thank you so much!

Comment: @John Added for you a complete sample listing that creates items in both collections and aggregates the result. Should be simple enough to follow now.

Comment: oh my god. still didn't work >_< what the hell... so i've tried to create a new project and copy your code and it works. but when i try to use on my existing project the same aggregate code you've use , i'm still receiving 0 on all ratings. oh my. i'll try to drop my database and fill it up and see if it will work

Comment: oh my god, what a fool i am. i am very sorry sir, so it's working now. so here's the problem. VERSION of the mongodb. So first of all, im using cloud database which is mlab, and when you asked me what version of mongodb im using, i check the version on my local machine the mongo, not on the cloud. mlab's version is 3.2.13. When upload the sample listing, i tried to use my local database and it works, now i tried to use mlab database (dropped all the collection) and it didn't work. So local db works, mlab db didn't, then i checked the version of mlab. oh my god. Thank you sir, sorry for trouble

Comment: from now on i won't use the cloud's database. oh my god, it's so outdated